# remove numbers string python

Tags: python, string

For my assignment, I have to create a function that returns a new string that is the same as the given string, but with digits removed.

Example: remove digits(’abc123’) would return the string ’abc’.

I have tried almost everything I can think off but it's not working properly :(

```
def test(str):
    for ch in str:
        num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9']
        if ch == num[0]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[1]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[2]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[3]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[4]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[5]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[6]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[7]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
        elif ch == num[8]:
            return str.replace(ch, '')
```

I enter test('abc123'), expecting the output to be 'abc'. But instead I get 'abc23' as my output.

In other attempts, same problem:

```
def test(str):
    for char in str:
        num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9']
        if char in list(num):
            return str.replace(char, '', len(str))
```

I get the same results.

Can anyone help me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's because you are returning from your funciton when you first encounter a number. `return` stops execution and exits the function!

Comment: Also, you can just check if `char in "0123456789"` which will simplify your code.

Answer (score 9):

Use regex

```
import re
def test(str):
    string_no_numbers = re.sub("\d+", " ", str)
    print(string_no_numbers)
test('abc123') #prints abc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
string = ''.join([c for c in string if c not in "1234567890"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is close:

```
def drop_digits(in_str):
    digit_list = "1234567890"
    for char in digit_list:
        in_str = in_str.replace(char, "")

    return in_str
```

The original problem is that you return after replacing only the '1' chars.

You can also do this with a list comprehension:

```
return ''.join([char for char in in_str if not char.isdigit()])
```

Comment: Might want to use a better variable name than the OP ;)

Comment: Good point.  Changing ...

Comment: thanks dude, really apreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on some python basics. The "return" exits your function, so it will only ever modify one entry.

Here's a hint: replace str with an updated copy instead of returning it.

```
str = str.replace(ch, '')
```

Comment: As for python basics... we are dealing with a function not a method here. This ain't Java ;)

Comment: eh, test could be in a class without the "self" argument here, if we are gonna be pedantic ;)

Comment: If we want to be *super* pedantic, test is not either because it has a indentation errors.

Comment: ^ definitely gotta agree

Answer (score -1):

```
def test(string):
    return ''.join((letter for letter in string if not letter.isdigit()))
```

Comment: This removes more than just digits.

Comment: probably want to check `if not letter.isdigit()`

Comment: I've used `not letter.isdigit()` but thought it will be kind of overkill and changed it to `.isalpha`, but re-changed it now.