# How to extract integers from a random string without using regex?

Tags: python

Say I have an arbitrary string like

```
"abc 123 def 456"
```

How would I take out the integers so that it can print "123456" without using regex?

Comment: `print "123456"` will do.

Comment: I dont think I worded it properly. I edited it so hopefully it makes more sense now. I need to extract the integers from any random string that could be given to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove numbers string python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906519/remove-numbers-string-python)

Comment: You can use `"".join(c for c in s if c.isdigit())`, where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your specific question, you can just use `.isdigit()`

```
s = "abc 123 def 456"

for ch in s:
    if ch.isdigit():
        print(ch, end='')
print()
```

Comment: please do not encourage zero effort questions

Comment: How is it zero effort? I think the first time I posted this it may have seemed like a dumb question, so I editied it.I need to extract the integers out of any string that is given to me, not just the specific one.

Comment: this will extract (print) integers from any given string

Comment: @Rionic I understand that very well and my "solution" was sarcastic, but you have shown no code, no search, no effort whatsoever to solve your problem.

Comment: This is just a part of my full question, but it's the part I can't figure out, so I decided to just leave out the rest of my code as it would be unecessary. I've been working on the question for quite a while now.